# Angular ng-repeat groupBy and Keep order

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Im  using this filter https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby to order my data like so, and it works great:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags.tags.objects | groupBy:'category.name' ">
```

Now Im trying to keep the order of that groups, by category.order.

Is this possible?

I tried piping it like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags.tags.objects | groupBy:'category.name' | orderBy:'category.order' ">
```

But it does not make any difference

Answer (score 18):

`orderBy` filter does not work with objects in `ngRepeat`. So, what you can do is something like this:

```
<!-- 
     Note: toArray filter also attaches a new property $key
     to the value containing the original key that was used in the object. 
-->

<div ng-repeat="tags in tagsList | groupBy:'prop' | toArray:true | orderBy:'$key'">
  Group name: {{ tags.$key }}
  <p ng-repeat="tag in tags | orderBy:'prop'">
     {{ tag.name }}
  </p>
</div>
```

See: [toArray](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#toarray) filter

Comment: this is refreshing my lists every time I make an edit to an object in my array now causing perforance issues, I think it has to do with the ToArray, any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

groupBy should always be the last one in the ng-repeat..
so set orderBy first and groupBy last and then you can use track by $index
so the normal ng-repeat will be.

```
ng-repeat="item in items orderBy:'price' | groupBy:'name' track by $index"
```

...
Hope it helps even its little late!

Comment: there's a `|` missing between `items` and `orderBy`

Answer (score 3):

To partially of djsiz's answer (track by isn't necessary and it was missing a pipe), you could do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags.tags.objects | orderBy:'category.order' | groupBy:'category.name'">
```

The groupBy creates an object but the orderBy needs an array... if you orderBy before you group, it should sort properly

https://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/kfho6r26/