# Angularjs directive - filter by key

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I just created a directive so that I'm able to reuse some code all over my app, but now I'm a bit stuck..

I have a directive that checks an object inside another object from a json file:

```
{
    "data" : [ {
            "iID" : 1,
            "iType" : 5,
            "objTimer" : [{
                    "iDay" : 0,
                    "iTm" : 0,
                    "fSP" : 9
                }, {
                    "iDay" : 0,
                    "iTm" : 3600,
                    "fSP" : 22
                },{
                    "iDay" : 1,
                    "iTm" : 63000,
                    "fSP" : 9
                }, {
                    "iDay" : 1,
                    "iTm" : 76500,
                    "fSP" : 28
                }, {
                    "iDay" : 2,
                    "iTm" : 63000,
                    "fSP" : 9
                } ......
            ],
            .....
        } ]
}
```

and prints it onscreen, and this is the code:

```
<li ng-repeat="timers in currentRoom.objTimer">
    <example-directive 
        timer="timers" 
        day="'{{timers.iDay}}'" 
        title="'Title'">
    </example-directive>
</li>
```

my directive.js code is the following:

```
angular.module('app.exampleDirective', [])
    .directive('exampleDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                timer: '=',
                day: '@',
                title: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "/templates/directiveTemplate/exampleDirective.html",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                console.log($scope.timer)
            }
        };
    })
```

and the directive template:

```
<div>
    {{title}} - {{day}}
    <pre>{{timer}}</pre>
</div>
```

Everything works as supposed to, but what I don't really know that *what is the best way to filter the data.*

The result from my directive on page is the following (I'm printing the values as JSON for the moment):

```
<div class="scroll">
  <!-- ngRepeat: timers in currentRoom.objTimer -->
    <li ng-repeat="timers in currentRoom.objTimer" class="">
       <div timer="timers" day="'0'" title="'Title'" class="ng-binding">
          Title - '0'
          <pre class="ng-binding">{"iDay":0,"iTm":0,"fSP":9}</pre>
        </div>
    </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: timers in currentRoom.objTimer -->
    <li ng-repeat="timers in currentRoom.objTimer" class="">
       <div timer="timers" day="'0'" title="'Title'" class="ng-binding">
          Title - '0'
          <pre class="ng-binding">{"iDay":0,"iTm":3600,"fSP":22}</pre>
       </div>
    </li>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: timers in currentRoom.objTimer -->
    <li ng-repeat="timers in currentRoom.objTimer" class="">
        <div timer="timers" day="'0'" title="'Title'" class="ng-binding">
           Title - '0'
           <pre class="ng-binding">{"iDay":0,"iTm":16200,"fSP":9}</pre>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: timers in currentRoom.objTimer -->
```

and so on...

What I'd like to do is basically divide them into block, so that all the one with iDay = 0 will be printed as a unique block.

Something pretty much like the following:

Days:

```
 Day-0:    
   - ..    
   - ..    
   - ..
_____________________________________
 Day-1:
   - ..    
   - ..    
   - ..    
_____________________________________
  Day-2:
   - ..
   - ..
```

But using the same directive.

Any idea on how to do this?

I tried to add a data attribute day in the directive, but now I'm stuck...should I use it as another repeater inside the directive template and filter the data by @index?

If you need more details please comment.

Comment: take a look at groupBy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921427/angular-ng-repeat-groupby-and-keep-order  or   http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-grouping-nested-ngrepeat-lists-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: If i do like the above mentioned answer, i get an error: Unknown provider: toArrayFilterProvider <- toArrayFilter

Comment: ok, sorted. It works. thanks

Comment: if you find a working solution past in response. it will help

Comment: Just used groupBy exactly as seen in this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921427/angular-ng-repeat-groupby-and-keep-order